# Am I allowed to use spells to get this Dishonored achievement?

Tags: pc, dishonored

I've been trying to get an achievement for ages but I can't figure it out. What do I have to do to kill a Tallboy with only my sword? **Does this mean I can't use spells?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can blink behind them and assassinate them from behind as seen in [This Video]: